# FacebookOAuthClient: Method GetLogoutUrl obsolete

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

The method GetLogoutUrl is marked as obsolete, but I can't find any replacement for it. Is there simply no replacement or am I just looking at the wrong place?

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356288/getlogouturl-method-missing-in-facebook-c-sdk-5-2-1-net-4][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356288/getlogouturl-method-missing-in-facebook-c-sdk-5-2-1-net-4