# GetLogoutUrl method missing in facebook c# sdk 5.2.1 .net 4

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

This method seems to be missing on the latest version of the sdk. Does anyone know why and what is the alternative method for logging out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetLogoutUrl method was marked obsolete in the previous releases as it doesn't provide the expected behavior. (you can read more about the details at http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17217)

You will need to use Facebook Javascript SDK to logout or programatically delete the cookies of the WebBrowser control inorder to logout of Facebook.

Comment: Which cookies should be expired?